# python print function in real time

Tags: python, printing, stdout, flush

I recently switched OS and am using a newer Python (2.7). On my old system, I used to be able to print instantaneously. For instance, suppose I had a computationally intense for loop:

```
for i in range(10):
  huge calculation
  print i
```

then as the code completed each iteration, it would print `i`

However, on my current system, python seems to cache the stdout so that the terminal is blank for several minutes, after which it prints:

```
1
2
3
```

in short succession. Then, after a few more minutes, it prints:

```
4
5
6
```

and so on. How can I make python print as soon as it reaches the `print` statement?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to call flush of stdout after the print

```
import sys

...
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Or use a [command line](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html) option -u which:

> Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but do you know how I can set this automatically?

Comment: @Rishi: The closest you could get to having it automatic (without having to resort to compiling your own version of python) would be to set the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable.

Comment: Jeff's comment was very useful to me. Thank you

Answer (score 14):

Since Python 3.3, you can simply pass [flush=True](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#print) to the print function.

Answer (score 4):

Import the new [print-as-function](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3105-print-as-a-function) as in Python 3.x:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

*(put the statement at the top of your script/module)*

This allows you to replace the new print function with your own:

```
def print(s, end='\n', file=sys.stdout):
    file.write(s + end)
    file.flush()
```

The advantage is that this way your script will work just the same when you upgrade one day to Python 3.x.

*Ps1: I did not try it out, but the print-as-function might just flush by default.*

*PS2: you might also be interested in my [progressbar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419984/print-to-the-same-line-and-not-a-new-line-in-python/7464288#7464288).*