# Carriage return escape character behaves like a newline in Python 3 and OS X

Tags: python, macos

I searched and couldn't find an answer to this.  I'm trying to use '\r' as a carriage return in a program but it behaves like a newline instead.  Here's the code I'm trying to use, adapted for Python 3 from "Learn Python the Hard Way"

```
while True:
    for i in ["/","-","|","\\","|"]:
        print("%s\r" % i, end='')
```

It's supposed to look like a little rotating bar, like a busy animation or something, but it prints each new character to a newline.  How do I get the carriage return to behave like an actual carriage return?

Comment: maybe you should print with a "," (comma character)? check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/3419991/583834

Comment: How are you invoking this program? Are you running in an IDE?

Comment: I'm running in IDLE.  I feel kind of silly now because I just ran it from the command line and it worked as expected.  @amp, that method only works in Python <3.