# How to print iterated strings in same lane of stdout (Windows cmd)?

Tags: python, terminal

I am using following code to display string with loop completition percentage:

```
for x in range(y,z):
    completed = 100*(x-y)/(z-y)
    sys.stdout.write(f'{completed:10.0f}% completed.'
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

And I want all the strings to be displayed in the same line of windows cmd (earlier value removed, and new printed in same place)

Output I want to obtain, should look like this:

> ```
>     x% completed.
> ```

Where x value is updated with each iteration.

But the output i get looks like this:

> ```
>     0% completed.         1% completed.         2% completed. ...etc
> ```

From what i found it should work on other platforms than Windows, but I am interested about Windows solution.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419984/print-to-the-same-line-and-not-a-new-line-in-python

Comment: While digging i only found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python
Do you mind to share what you input into search?

Comment: This is what I googled: "python terminal print same line"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `\r` at the end of the string:

```py
for x in range(y,z):
    completed = 100*(x-y)/(z-y)
    sys.stdout.write(f'{completed:10.0f}% completed.  \r'
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

unless you have some buffering issues you should be able to use `print` directly:

```py
for x in range(y,z):
    completed = 100*(x-y)/(z-y)
    print(f'{completed:10.0f}% completed.  ', end='\r')
```