# How to print multiple lines on one line

Tags: python-3.x, string, printing

**I am getting this:**

```
0.0  angry27.56%
0.0  disgust0.0%
0.0  fear18.75%
0.0  happy14.47%
0.0  sad5.34%
0.0  surprise14.96%
0.0  neutral18.92%
```

**I want to get this:**

```
0.0  angry27.56%, disgust0.0%, fear18.75%, happy14.47%, sad5.34%, surprise14.96%, neutral18.92%
```

**I am using this code:**

```
emotion = ""
        for i in range(len(predictions[0])):
            emotion = "%s%s%s" % (emotions[i], round(predictions[0][i]*100, 2), '%')
            print(str(sec)+ "  " + emotion)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print to the same line and not a new line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419984/print-to-the-same-line-and-not-a-new-line-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
print(str(sec)+ "  " + emotion,end=', ')
```

`end=' '` parameter inside the print statement can be used to print output in a single line....

Comment: its a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419984/print-to-the-same-line-and-not-a-new-line-in-python?r=SearchResults

Comment: I tried it but all in vain!!! Now I am getting

0.0  angry 27.56% 0.0  disgust 0.0% 0.0  fear 18.75% 0.0  happy 14.47% 0.0  sad 5.34% 0.0  surprise 14.96% 0.0  neutral 18.92% 0.04  angry 1.0% 0.04  disgust 0.0% 0.04  fear 5.16% 0.04  happy 1.97% 0.04  sad 1.19% 0.04  surprise 5.57% 0.04  neutral 85.12% 0.08  angry 0.51% 0.08  disgust 0.0% 0.08  fear 5.36% 0.08  happy 0.3% 0.08  sad 1.27% 0.08  surprise 5.47% 0.08  neutral 87.08% 0.12  angry 0.82% 0.12  disgust 0.0% 0.12  fear 5.5% 0.12  happy 0.15% 0.12  sad 2.65% 0.12  surprise 2.45% 0.12  neutral 88.42%

Comment: Use `end=', '`  comma and space inside single quote and execute it again...

Answer (score 1):

First create a empty list then append all values of emotion in it then use join() to combine elements of list :

```
emotion = ""
res = []
for i in range(len(predictions[0])):
    emotion = "%s%s%s" % (emotions[i], round(predictions[0][i] * 100, 2), '%')
    res.append(emotion)
print(str(sec), end=" ")
print(", ".join(res))
```