# In python, how do I make a string overlap a current string in the shell?

Tags: python, loops, shell, replace, display

Each second, it prints a new line.
Is there a way to have it print ontop of the previous line?

```
while True:
    sec += 1
    if sec / 60 == sec_int:
        sec = 0
        mins += 1
        if mins / 60 == min_int:
            mins = 0
            hours += 1
            if hours / 24 == hour_int:
                hours = 0
                days += 1
    print(f"{days}d : {hours}h : {mins}m : {sec}s")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: It's easier if you paste the code instead of an image. `end='\r' might work in the print: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419984/print-to-the-same-line-and-not-a-new-line

Comment: Not just easier, we _outright disallow_ questions that only include images or links and not enough information to concretely answer the question or learn from answers with only what's in the body text itself; the [mre] definition requires a reproducer to be included _in the question itself_. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) -- it's unreasonable to ask someone to retype text from your screenshot to be able to see a problem themselves or test a proposed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your print statement with:

```
print(f"\r{days}d : {hours}h : {mins}m : {sec}s", end="", flush=True)
```

`"\r"` is a "control character" which moves the cursor to the beginning of the line ("carriage Return").  `flush=True` is needed to make the display update right away--normally Python can buffer until a newline is written, which of course you'll never write (because there's no way to go back up to a previous line).